# How to fix "python does not have .gnu.prelink_undo section"

Tags: python, virtualenv, packaging, rpmbuild

I need to package a virtualenv as an rpm.  I found a sample spec file for plone [here](https://github.com/pingviini/rhel6-rpmbuild/blob/master/rpmbuild/SPECS/plone3-virtualenv.spec)

My project uses python 2.7 and for that I've built python from source.  Therefore I changed some of the spec file to

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv-3.4 --no-site-packages --distribute %{_builddir}/usr/local/virtualenvs/%{shortname}
```

I'm getting the following error on `rpmbuild -bb requirements.spec`

```
+ /usr/sbin/prelink -u /var/lib/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/requirements-1.0-1.x86_64/usr/local/virtualenvs/requirements/bin/python
/usr/sbin/prelink: /var/lib/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/requirements-1.0-1.x86_64/usr/local/virtualenvs/requirements/bin/python does not have .gnu.prelink_undo section
```

I'm assuming I need to rebuild python and enable the prelinking during the `./configure`.  How can I do that?

Comment: I think you accidentally used the wrong tag. `rspec` is a testing library for Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently with a SPEC file that was also based on this example from plone.

In my case I'm using python27 RPMs from IUS repository and want to avoid building it from source.

My workaround was to disable prelink completely in my SPEC file:

- add this:  `%define __prelink_undo_cmd %{nil}`
- comment out this:

  `# # This avoids prelink & RPM helpfully breaking the package signatures:`

  `# /usr/sbin/prelink -u $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/virtualenvs/%{shortname}/bin/python`